# sp_flush_commit_table_on_demand procedure running even on AG

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2017

I am not sure if this is a bug or not but i am seeing calls on sp_flush_commit_table_on_demand when running async AG.

I wouldnt have a problem with that unless i wanted to capture last commit time value which is changing when this procedure executed (every half n hour). 
I dont have any replication or cdc enabled, so it is a clear instance with one AG setup only. No jobs or any other calls. 
I couldnt find documentation about this correlation between this SP and AG.

If anyone can clarify this behavior, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like change tracking is enabled on something... what's sys.change_tracking_databases say?

Comment: Its empty......